# How to deal with static methods in a WCF service?

Tags: c#, wcf, static, singleton

I am a beginner to WCF. I am trying to make a device driver network accessible.
Code I have right now, simplified:

### A.cs

```
public class A {
    public int source;
}
```

### Driver.cs

```
public class Driver {
    // some fields here
    A a;

    // singleton class
    private Driver() {
        a = null;
        // some more code
    }

    // static methods
    public static Driver OpenDevice(int n) {
        Driver d = null;
        // some code
        i = GetBoardNumber();
        // some native code to actually open driver ONLY IF it wasn't already opened!
        d = new Driver();
        return d;
    }
    public static int GetDeviceNumber() {
        // some native code get device number
        return someInt;
    }

    // some non static methods which use native code
    // example:
    public int ResetDevice(){
        // some code
        // call native i_ResetDevice() method
        return code;
    }
}
```

### DllImport.cs

```
public class DllImport {
    // some code to import method definitions from dll
    // example:
    [DllImport("MyDeviceDriverProvidedForWindows.dll")]
        public static extern int i_ResetDevice();
    // some more code
}
```

This Driver works very well for me. In the examples that control the device, I simply add reference to this Driver and control the Device using driver's methods.

```
MyService d = Driver.OpenDevice(0);
d.ControlDevice();
```

My job is to make this Driver *remotely* accessible, and I chose to do it using WCF.

Since, I already had implementation, I extracted an interface and turned it into a valid WCF service contract by putting OperationContracts and proper places. This extracted interface did not have the OpenDevice and GetDeviceNumber methods because, they were static.

---

The problems I am having are:

1) Opening WSDL file tells me to use some code like this in client:

```
MyServiceClient client = new MyServiceClient();
// access client operations
// close client
client.Close();
```

what is this `MyServiceRefernce.MyServiceClient`(`MyServiceReference` is name of the service reference I added to the client)? Why is it calling the private constructor of MyService class on server?

2) How can I do something like this in the client?

```
MyServiceReference.Driver d = MyServiceRefernce.Driver.OpenDevice(0);
```

I have read about `InstanceContextMode` but not really sure how to use it my situation.

I understand it is hard to understand what I am asking exactly, but it really is hard for me to explain too! I wish I had someone with me who knew WCF well.

---

The actual driver source I am using is in Assembly folder in [this file](http://bit.ly/UaVhF8).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You not make a WCF service use a single instance by making the service class a singleton. You need to configure the WCF service so it uses only a single instance. Also you can create a session-based WCF service. See [this](http://soumya.wordpress.com/2010/05/26/wcf-simplified-part-8-sessions-instance-management-and-concurrency/), for example.

Comment: Thank you. The example was **excellent**. I moved code from my static method `CreateInstance` to private constructor (it was a singleton class) and used - SessionMode:Required, InstanceManagement:Single, Concurrency:Reentrant.

Answer (score 2):

Normally WCF has no sessions, so all calls are independ of each other. So you should encapsulate the Driver functions into servicable methods. So one method will service an unit of work for a the device, which will be opened -> do work -> closed at each call.

Comment: I ended up using sessions. Thanks for your answer :)